# how to run test method multiple times for different values

Tags: java, testng, selenium-grid

I have just started using selenium grid with Testing tool for a web testing.

I have a class with this method @Test, I have hardcoded the URL here and wrote multiple methods with different URLs. but i want to pass those URL values from a txt file and the class should launch the
methods parallely for each URL from the txt file. please let me know how I can do it

```
@Test(description = "Showing bing")    
@Parameters({"seleniumHost", "seleniumPort", "browser", "webSite"})
public void bing(String seleniumHost, int seleniumPort, String rowser, String webSite) throws Throwable {

 try {
    startSeleniumSession(seleniumHost, seleniumPort, browser, webSite);
    Base b = new Base();
    b.setInitialUrl("http://www.bing.com");
    b.setMaxCount(30);
    AssertJUnit.assertTrue(b.InitiateTest());

} finally {    
    closeSeleniumSession(); }
}
```

Can I use @Factory annotation here? Can you help me how I do write that class and place it where? I'am not using testng.xml here.

Please help.

Comment: It would help if you format your question and add a testng tag to it.

Answer (score 2):

To pass multiple data to your test, you can use testNG dataprovider. Details are clearly mentioned [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you need.